# SharedPreferences putInt method not working

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

```
private boolean rightReviewTiming() {
    int insertKitCnt = sharedPreferences.getInt("insert_kit_cnt",0);
    insertKitCnt++;
    sharedPreferences.edit().putInt("insert_kit_cnt", insertKitCnt);
    sharedPreferences.edit().commit();
    insertKitCnt = sharedPreferences.getInt("insert_kit_cnt", 0);
    Log.d("ehhehe", "rightReviewTiming: " + insertKitCnt);
    if((insertKitCnt % 11 == 0) && (insertKitCnt % 2 == 0)) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

I want to update `insert_kit_cnt` key. But, its log always shows '0'. If you know where is the issue, please let me know about that. I think maybe `insert_kit_cnt` commit is not working. Is commit timing wrong?

Comment: Try to use `apply()` instead of `commit()`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do the `commit` or `apply` on the editor that you're making change on.

```
sharedPreferences.edit().putInt("insert_kit_cnt", insertKitCnt).apply();
```

Answer (score 2):

You are creating two editor references. You need to use only one reference of editor:

```java
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
editor.putInt("insert_kit_cnt", insertKitCnt);
editor.apply();
```

Or in one-liner code, you can also do like this:

```
sharedPreferences.edit().putInt("insert_kit_cnt", insertKitCnt).apply();
```